# locked out of screen

Tags: login-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell laptop. It's my 'pro' machine at work, and almost every morning, I come in and the cleaners have put things on top of it, and I have a long line of * at the password prompt.  Holding down backspace for ages doesn't help, and I need to reboot.

Just there, I was sitting at my desk having lunch, and stupidly sat my Kindle on the keyboard, with the same result.  I switched to a virtual console and tried to kill the screen lock, but to no avail.  So I rebooted, which wouldn't be a problem, except that I was running two `rsync` and `mv` scripts, which had been running since 8 AM, and which now need to be restarted.

Is there any way to get back from this dead lock screen, without killing one's session?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of backspace try Home+End and when its all highlighted tap Del.

Comment: What happens when you press CTRL-A and backspace in the password field?

Comment: Shift+Home I mean...

Comment: Alternative unplug keyboard and turn it upside down when leaving work :)

Comment: (the HOME END bit .. not putting the keyboard upside down. ;-) )